# Are Statistics questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently [attempted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774623/151595) to answer a question about statistics on MSE, but didn't bother with completing my answer because there was too little traffic on the question and the OP took no interest. I wasn't sure what the general approach is to statistics questions on MSE - do they add to the site, and thus should be answered in order to help other users? Or should they be flagged for migration to Cross Validated?

The question I linked above was downvoted, and didn't attract the usual good quality answers or comments (even though it is a poorly asked question). Was it down-voted because it was off-topic?

Comment: "Are Statistics questions off-topic?" No. "Was it down-voted because it was off-topic?" No, because it was terrible.

Comment: The linked question is not even a Statistics question at all. It's pure probability.

Comment: @Meta I think the question requires a paired t-test to determine if the mean of the difference between the test scores is close to 3 or not.

Comment: There is nothing like that in the question.

Comment: @Meta the scores presumably come from the same tests, so the data is not independent.